# Django Model Admin: How to auto assign and hide created_by field with current user and display after save?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working certain model  Accounting which consists of following model attributes.

```
class Accounting(model.Model):
    booking = models.OneToOneField(Booking, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[])
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bus_company = models.ForeignKey(BusCompany, models.PROTECT)
```

in admin.py I have done so far

```
@admin.register(Accounting)
class AccountingAdmin(ModelAdmin):
      list_display =(
        'bus_company',
        'description ',
        'bus_company ',
    )
```

Now when I use Django admin for adding `Accounting`. I want to hide `created_by` and want to set the current logged in user as the `created_by`. Currently it is `superuser` so after adding of data The created_by fields also gets update and displayed how can I do this?

Comment: Are you aware that *normal users* can't login to Django Admin?

Comment: Yes I know that but If i got other user to for ex. IF normal user is looged in than with no knowledge of normal user I want  created_by to be assigned as normal user in created_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added read_only fields in admin

```
@admin.register(Accounting)
class AccountingAdmin(ModelAdmin):
      list_display =(
        'bus_company',
        'description ',
        'bus_company ',
    )
    readonly_fields = (
        'created_by',

    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the filed , set editable to False

```
created_by = models.Model(editable=False)
```

Now , also add blank=True to created_by and overwrite the save method :

```
created_by = models.Model(blank=True,null=True,editable=False)
def save(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
    user = user
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Now at the time of saving this object:

```
def view_name(request):
    user = request.user
    atributes = {'booking':'blabl','description':'blablablab'
    ,'bus_company':'blab blab'}
    account = Account(**atributes)
    account.save(user=user)
```

Comment: got error Accounting  object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Oh sorrry ! forgot that.

Comment: Now, add , after self, another parameter called request which you'll pass at the time of saving the object and inseated of saying self.request write request.user

Comment: please once go through my answer below